# How to split this txt file into small files using shell scripting?

Tags: file, shell, awk, split

I would like to spilt a txt file into small ones. However, I did not know how to script using shell. If someone could help, it will be greatly appreciated!

The file  I would like to split like this:

```
name    Onsetime    duration    weight
s002_run1_fng   122.6 2 1
s002_run1_fng   144.8 2 1
s002_run1_fyg   132.6 2 1
s002_run1_fyg   182.6 2 1
s002_run1_fyg   198.6 2 1
s002_run1_fyg   230.6 2 1
s002_run1_fyg   308.6 2 1
s002_run1_fyg   368.6 2 1
s002_run1_fyg   382.6 2 1
s002_run1_fyg   410.6 2 1
s002_run1_fnl   294.8 2 1
s002_run1_fnl   394.8 2 1
s002_run1_fyl   66.6 2  1
s002_run1_fyl   78.6 2  1
s002_run1_fyl   158.6 2 1
s002_run1_fyl   207.1 2 1
s002_run1_fyl   257.4 2 1
s002_run1_fyl   269.2 2 1
s002_run1_fyl   319.2 2 1
s002_run1_fyl   327.3 2 1
s002_run1_fnn   52.8 2  1
s002_run1_fnn   280.7 2 1
s002_run1_fnn   350.8 2 1
s002_run1_fyn   96.6 2  1
s002_run1_fyn   110.6 2 1
s002_run1_fyn   169.3 2 1
```

I would like to split the file into the new txt files, the first column will be the name of the new file, and the second to the fourth column is the content of the new file. If the first column is the same, the second to the fourth column will be composed a new file. For example, the content of the first file is

```
122.6 2 1
144.8 2 1
```

and the new file name would be "`s002_run1_fng`"

How to code using shell ?

Thank you! Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hmm, SO isn't meant to be a place where you're just given code, so, some starters: you'll need to loop through your current text file; within the loop, split the columns up by white space, create a file, print stuff to that file, and close the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an awk one-liner may do what you want, give it a try:

```
awk 'NR>1{print $2,$3,$4 > $1}' file
```

Comment: Yes, your code is work! Great! Thank you very much! Or I have do it manually. It is so time-consuming. 

However, there is another problem. When I run the code you provided, the terminal said:

awk: s002_run3_fyn makes too many open files
 input record number 87, file feedback.txt
 source line number 1

It just generated 17 files. How Can I solve this problem? 

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Yangmei glad to help. for the too many opened file problem you could try this:  first remove all generated files from last run, if there are any. then exeucte `awk 'NR>1{print $2,$3,$4 >> $1;close( $1)}' file`

Comment: Thank you for your kind help so much! The code works! The work have done in two second. I am highly appreciated!
However, when I use the same code to the file, which has similar structure, it did not work. The terminal did not report error, but it did not generate file.Could you help me again? Thank you!
name anticipation duration weight
s002_run1_ag 116.761 2 1
s002_run1_ag 128.755 2 1
s002_run1_ag 138.763 2 1
s002_run1_ag 178.762 2 1
s002_run1_ag 190.771 2 1
s002_run1_ag 226.75 2 1
s002_run1_ag 304.764 2 1
s002_run1_ag 360.759 2 1
s002_run1_ag 374.77 2 1
s002_run1_ag 404.761 2 1